# HTTPContext issues (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, httpcontext

Hey guys, this is a weird one!

I have a site that I have deployed in 3 places. 1. My local machine. 2. Dev Server 3.QA Server. My project runs on my machine and the dev server. On the QA server, it runs, but the HTTPContext object is blank (not pulling from AD, etc).

All 3 machines live on the domain.
The Dev Server and QA Server are configured identically (or so Im told).
The Dev and QA Servers IIS entries are 99% identical (path names, etc are different).

Has anyone ever had this issue? It seems that the HTTPContext is just not being populated on the QA box, but the other 2 are just fine. Could there be a setting Im missing? Has anyone ever run into this before?

Thanks.

Comment: We're running into this now.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I was unable to get a solution, so I came up with something and worked around it.